# Did I install the end link incorrectly?

Tags: mazda, miata, swaybar

I found out after sending my vehicle, a 93 miata, to a shop for a control arm replacement that it was missing the drivers side anti-sway bar link along with the hardware. After heading to a hardware store and ordering the new part I installed the new end links on both sides. Weeks later after doing an alignment for my vehicle I found out later after inspecting it due to noise that the link got removed from its bushing and was hanging lose. Again I ordered a second link and installed it. Now today after jacking up my vehicle and accidentally dropping the vehicle a little too quickly the link again got removed from its bushing and was hanging lose.

My questions are what would cause the end link to snap like this twice? did I chose the wrong hardware for it? (it is not a 100% match) did I torque it incorrectly (both times torqued to specs) or I just simply dropped the vehicle too fast, but an alignment shop would not make that mistake would they?

EDIT: picture of end link [image]

Comment: Did it pop out of the sway bar or did the bolt which hold the whole thing together snap? A picture would be invaluable here.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The link popped out of its own bushing and the bushing is still on the sway bar with the hardware. I will take a picture in a few hours

Comment: That is bizarre. Did you purchase the end link from the same source both times? Maybe they just have a manufacturing problem.

Comment: Here is a thread where somebody else ran into the same problem https://www.reddit.com/r/Miata/comments/2br1j7/popping_sway_bar_end_link/ Did you purchase Moog end links by chance?

Comment: @rviertel wow I even used the same brand I guess a manufacturing issue by Moog

Comment: @method I've always had a good experience with Moog parts, but I guess they got this one wrong.

Comment: @rivertel can you post your first comment as an answer? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a thread where somebody else ran into the same problem https://www.reddit.com/r/Miata/comments/2br1j7/popping_sway_bar_end_link/

Did you purchase Moog end links by chance? It looks like they might have a manufacturing problem with this part.

Comment: I was going to say it sounds like a brand problem to me as well. Either buy OEM or start looking at reviews before you buy.